# How to unit-test for PHP implicit conversion errors?

Tags: php, unit-testing

Is there a way to find errors caused by crafted input in php, such as naming POST-fields like `variable[]` instead of `variable`, causing PHP to implicitly convert it into an array, by using some form of automated testing?

Comment: Could you detail the kind of testing you have in mind? Ideally whatever code consumes the POST data would have its own validation logic.

Answer (score 1):

Use type assertions as annotations in the code:

```
class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Type("string")
     */
    protected $firstName;

    /**
     * @Assert\Type(
     *     type="integer",
     *     message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid {{ type }}."
     * )
     */
    protected $age;
}
```

Or `settype` in the tests themselves:

```
$foo = "42";
echo gettype($foo); // Yields "string"
// Here we change the type from string -> integer
settype($foo, "integer");
echo gettype($foo); // Yields "integer"
```

**References**

- [PHP Manual: settype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php)
- [Type (Symfony Docs)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Type.html)